# does #apt-get..... mean the same as sudo apt-get

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I'm looking some command line instructions. I'm supposed to have Ubuntu Linux Server with Python 2.7 (and why can't there be a simple explanation of how to get Python 2.7 on your ULS somewhere!). (Edit -- apparently Python 2.7 is built in, my bad!).

One of the first command line instructions is:
"#apt-get install build-essential pkg-config git-core python-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libxslt1-dev groff-base"

What does the # symbol mean? Is it a placeholder for sudo?

Comment: No - `#` is probably the notation used to depict the command prompt. Something like `#> apt-get ...` or `$> apt-get ...`

Comment: no just run `sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config git-core python-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libxslt1-dev groff-base`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is just letting you know that the command should be executed with superuser privileges (i.e. with `sudo`, which means "**su**peruser **do**"). It's supposed to represent the default prompt for root:

```
root@hostname / # ls -a
```

While the dollar sign is used to represent the prompt for an unprivileged user:

```
someone@hostname ~ $ ls -a
```